# how to fix : app keeps stopping android studio

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

I am developing an app that contains a login and signup page. It contains a homepage from where the user gets to navigate to signup or login page. My signup page works fine but when I hit login on the homepage the app closes.

> Please take a look at my 
>   [acttivity_login.xml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14nA9BkjtBWCYofI7U1wLZ1KaMFWMeGZu) file , I was not able to add it as a code snippet.
>
> the following is the java code for the start activity

```
package com.cuboid.chatapp;
```

public class start extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Button loginBtn, signupBtn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_login);
    signupBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_signup);

    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(start.this, login.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

    signupBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(start.this, signup.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

> > the following is the code for my login.java

```
package com.cuboid.chatapp;
```

public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
public  String email;
public String password;
private Button login_btn, forgotPassword_btn;
private FirebaseAuth auth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(login.this, contentChoice.class));
        finish();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    login_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
    forgotPassword_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_forgot_pwd);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter an email ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            loginUser();
        }
    });


}
public void  loginUser()
{
   auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
           .addOnCompleteListener(login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                       Toast.makeText(login.this, "Authentication failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, contentChoice.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
               }
           });
}
```

}

> The following is the Logcat error.

```
-03-25 17:12:44.060 11688-11688/com.cuboid.chatapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cuboid.chatapp, PID: 11688
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cuboid.chatapp/com.cuboid.chatapp.login}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.cuboid.chatapp.login.onCreate(login.java:44)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
```

I have no Idea about what this error is all about.
Somebody please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: logcat please share.

Comment: Share your `activity_login.xml` as well. Make sure the id for login button is set correctly as `login_btn`. The null pointer exception usually means that your given ID for that button was not found in the xml.

Comment: Please share your activity .XML file. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I have edited the question by adding a link to login_activity.xml. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that one of these assignments returned null:

```
loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_login);
signupBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_signup);
```

That means the view with the passed ID was not found in the layout.  You will have to figure out what view you actually meant to find, and use the correct ID.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I figured it out, Android studio had created an xml file called activity_login.xml(v26) and that in turn did not have a button in the layout. I am very much new to android programming.
Can anyone please tell me why android studio does that ?